# Html Agility Pack is lower casing cAsE SeNSiTive SVG attributes

Tags: .net, svg, html-agility-pack

The viewBox (note the capital "B") is a case sensitive attribute. Changing the value to "viewbox" can cause the  element to render incorrectly or not at all.

HtmlAgilityPack is defaulting all (X)HTML attributes to lowercase. How can I prevent this?

**Example HTML page with a valid SVG element (Note the camel case viewBox attribute):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #000007">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 800">
            <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#000007" width="600" height="100%"/>
            <image width="600" height="800" xlink:href="images/cover.jpg" transform="translate(0 0)" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

**To keep things simple, lets say I want to add a title tag (if missing).**

```
 Private Function InsertTitleTagIfMissing(p_content As String) As String
        Dim _pageContent = p_content
        Dim _doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
        _doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = True

        _doc.LoadHtml(p_content)

        Dim _head = _doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head")
        Dim _title = _head.SelectSingleNode("title")

        If _title Is Nothing Then
            _title = _doc.CreateElement("title")
            _head.AppendChild(_title)
            _pageContent = _doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
        End If

        Return _pagecontent

    End Function

    Private Sub LoadTestFile
        Dim _exampleFileName = "C:\_testPage\cover.html"
        Dim _strContents As String = String.empty


        using _objReader = New StreamReader(_exampleFileName, True)
            _strContents = _objReader.ReadToEnd()
            _objReader.close
        End Using

        _strContents = InsertTitleTagIfMissing(_strContents)

        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
    End Sub
```

**Output (i.e. value of _strContents) (Note the viewbox attribute is now lower case.):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #000007">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 600 800">
            <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#000007" width="600" height="100%"></rect>
            <image width="600" height="800" xlink:href="images/cover.jpg" transform="translate(0 0)"></image>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There seems to be a `HtmlDocument.OptionOutputAsXml`, see https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/master/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlDocument.cs#L128

Comment: I just tried that option and sadly the results are the same. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @ccprog I think you're on to something here. If I set HtmlDocument.OptionOutputAsXml = True and HtmlDocument.OptionOutputOriginalCase = True (both MUST be set to true). I get the desired results. Without your assistance, I wouldn't have found this. Feel free to answer the question and I'll give you credit for it.

Comment: As a principle, I don't answer questions in programming languages I don't know. (Is that VB?) You can answer yourself.

Comment: I understand, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of @ccprog, the solution I came up with is to set OptionOutputAsXml and OptionOutputOriginalCase to TRUE.

```
Private Function InsertTitleTagIfMissing(p_content As String) As String
    Dim _pageContent = p_content
    Dim _doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
    _doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = True
    _doc.OptionOutputAsXml = True
    _doc.OptionOutputOriginalCase = true

    _doc.LoadHtml(p_content)

    Dim _head = _doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head")
    Dim _title = _head.SelectSingleNode("title")

    If _title Is Nothing Then
        _title = _doc.CreateElement("title")
        _head.AppendChild(_title)
        _pageContent = _doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
    End If

    Return _pagecontent

End Function
```